# Regex match multiple comma separated strings inside quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string, datetime

I would like to have a tag with a comma separated list of parameters surrounded inside quotation marks. Some other requirements are:

1. Allow users to type in custom datetime format strings in Microsoft c# DateTime class format found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Have punctuation within these strings.
3. Have named groupings (see the demo) for all the parameters found  found in each overall match for example:

   ```
   Match 1.
   fullString "..."
   tag "..."
   param "..."
   param "..."
   ```

Example valid strings/tags:

> {DateTime}
>
> {datetime, "dd mmm yyyy"}
>
> {dAtetime, "dd mmm yyyy", "dddc"}
>
> {datetime, "hh.mm tt dd/MM/yyyy"}

Currently regex is only picking up on one parameter in the list.. what am I missing?

Current Regex: `(?<fullString>\{(?<tag>datetime)(?:\,\s*\"+(?<param>.+?)\"\s*)*\})`

[regex demo link](https://regex101.com/r/zK1kK4/2)

Comment: Allmost `(?:(?:\{(?<tag>datetime)[\s,]*)|(?:[\s,]*))(?:"(?:(?<param>(?:""|[^"])+)|)"[,\s\}]*)` but 3 656 steps...

Comment: @Tonio, the # of steps is not important, and does not really reflect a pattern performance. .NET regex works a bit differently than PCRE, it will not freeze where PCRE would, for example. oli_taz  Why did you test a .NET regex at regex101 that does not support .NET syntax?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can work with regex better with this provider. I usually make minor modifications to the regex string once I place it in a .Net application.. I'm not that used to .Net or Regex, is there a major difference in syntax that I haven't seen yet?

Comment: Certainly. Try `(?<!cat.*)dogs` against `People like dogs` and `cats do not like dogs` at both sites.